# Button text shows in Design, but is not available when I run the app

Tags: android, android-layout, button

The text on the button is not visible when the application is run on a device.

[image]

Here are the button's attribute

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    tools:text="Login"/>
```

Comment: Add your button's layout.

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        tools:text="Login"/>

Comment: Set a background to the button.

Answer (score 2):

Change `tools:text` (used in Design only) to `android:text` to make the text show up when running the app.